# How to Resolve "Remove unused JavaScript" in WordPress Website?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I have been trying since last more then 20 days to improve page speed score and trying my best to get fix as much as possible all suggestion has been given by Google Page Speed Insights, but still there are following suggestions/errors I can't fixed and couldn't find any single solution which can remove this error single time in try & testing process.

- Eliminate render-blocking resources
- Reduce initial server response time
- Remove unused JavaScript

[Website Google PageSpeed Insights Test](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hitechcaddservices.com%2F)

Please help me in this.

Currently, I am using following Plugins for Page Speed / Caching purpose.

- Autoptimize
- Fast Velocity Minify
- W3 Total Cache

But they are 60-70% successful to help but still my page scores won't get enough to good.

Technically my Home page has separate style-sheet and java-scripts then entire project so atleast homepage should have good score compare to other pages/posts.

But Google PageSpeed Insights suggesting 2 Java-scripts which i can't remove. **Specially How to get done with Google Tag Manager JS**?

Thanks.

Comment: "Remove unused JavaScript" is just a recommendation. The computer isn't as smart as you so it isn't going to know *exactly* what's used and what's not. Just look through your code and remove things you won't use.

Comment: Have a look at the Asset Cleanup plugin or the Pro version. You can unload plugins across the front end that aren't needed everywhere. For instance you May have a contact form plugin like contact form 7 with ACP you can unload CF7 site wide and only load it on your contact page. I've gone from scores of 16 to 65 on certain pages just from getting rid of the clutter caused by plugins.

Answer (score 2):

The "remove unused JavaScript" message is a recommendation from Google, because unused JavaScript means more data that needs to be transferred but that's not necessary.

Please note, it is a **recommendation** and the system may not know exactly what's used and what is not.

Also, in the most cases you can't remove all JavaScript that's unused, because technically you would have to remove every line of code that's not used on that specific page.

So, don't try to get that message removed too long, it's just a recommendation if there is more JavaScript found than Google thinks that is executed.

Comment: I couldn't have said it better. I, myself find it frustrating that Google audits sometimes will keep on saying "remove unused JavaScript" when I don't have much JavaScript that isn't used, but that doesn't necessarily mean that I *do* have unused JavaScript. A tip I do have though is try to find a way to spread out JavaScript execution, AKA only execute JavaScript when necessary at that specific time.